# Ploting boxplot as a function of a parameter (coin toss and frequency fluctuation)

Tags: r, boxplot

I have written a small sim of coins toss:

```
frequencePile <- function(repetition)
{
  lances <- sample(0:1,repetition,rep=T)
  piles <- sum(lances)
  freqP <-piles/length(lances)
  return(freqP)
}
###################
essais <- function(Nessais, rep){
  frequences <-{}
  for (e in 1:Nessais)
    {
    frequences <-c(frequences, frequencePile(rep))
  }
  return(frequences)
}
##################
effetRepvsFluct <- function (repetitionMin,repetitionMax, step,TailleEssai){
  ###créons un data frame vide~ feuille de calcul
  sim <- data.frame()
  essai<-TailleEssai
  for (r in seq(repetitionMin,repetitionMax,step)){
    df <- data.frame(r,essais(essai,r))
    sim <-rbind(sim,df)
  }
  return(sim)
}

NRepetition <-500
Nessais <- 300


fp<-frequencePile(NRepetition)
print (fp)
essai1 <-essais(Nessais,NRepetition)

#### Effet  repetition sur la fluctuation ####
TailleEssai<-200
repetitionMin<-10
repetitionMax<-500
repetitionPas<-10
simPF <- effetRepvsFluct(repetitionMin,repetitionMax,repetitionPas,TailleEssai)
colnames(simPF)<-c("répétition","fréquence")

plot(simPF)
```

and I'd like to plot boxplot as a function of a parameter. I have a dataframe:

```
str(simPF)
'data.frame':   10000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ répétition: num  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ fréquence : num  0.6 0.4 0.5 0.3 0.1 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.3 0.3 ...
```

when frequency as ploted against repetition size, I get:
[image: freq vs number of toss]
How to have boxplot instead of points? The following idea failed:

```
boxplot(simPF[2]~simPF[1], simPF)
Erreur dans model.frame.default(formula = simPF[2] ~ simPF[1], data = simPF) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'simPF[2]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[[` and not `[`:

```
boxplot(simPF[[2]]~simPF[[1]])
```

On a list or data frame, `[` will return another list or data frame, just as `[` on a vector will return another vector.

```
str(simPF[1])
# 'data.frame': 10000 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ répétition: num  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
```

On the other hand `[[` will return a single element of a list or a single column from a data frame.

```
str(simPF[[1]])
# num [1:10000] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
```

You received the error message because you passed in a data frame (a consequence of `[`) instead of a vector.

Better yet, just use the names of the columns:

```
boxplot(fréquence~répétition, simPF)
```